# I do not know how to approach this coin problem, where to start?

Tags: probability

When you throw a coin, you can either win $10$ dollars if heads or lose $5$ dollars if tails. After $100$ throws, you win $895$ dollars. Is this a fair coin? What probabilities can you associate with each side of the coin?

Can you please explain how to approach such questions, how to pull out the needed formulas from the wordings? In this case, I honestly do not even remotely know where to start. I was thinking about the expected values. I think this is not a fair coin, but then I can't associate any probabilities to it.

Comment: $10x - 5(100-x) = 895 \iff x = 93$. If the coin is fair, how many heads do you expect on average?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is a fair *coin* or a fair **bet**?

Comment: I have literally copy pasted the question from my lecturer's notes. So I have no idea what he wanted from us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fair coin, the number of heads after 100 throws should be $N\cdot p=50$, and the standard deviation of this number should be $\sqrt{Npq}=5$. By the stated rules, the win with $n$ out of $100$ heads is $10n-5(100-n)=15n-500$. We conclude that $n=\frac{895+500}{15}=93$. This differs by $\frac{93-50}{5}=8.6$ standard deviations - something so unlikely that people might call virtually impossible.

Comment: The net profit equals $15n-500$, not $500+5n$.

Comment: @jvdhooft oops! Such things happen when you already "see" that the numbers are way out of bounds and the wrong computation supports that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer
I hope it helps
you can also read "a very short introduction to probability " published by oxfor union press , its a nice read.
[image: page 1]

Comment: Please do not post answers in this way. Always convert your notes digitally, as this is much easier to read.